# Laravel Ajax runs in 500 Internal Server Error although Token is created

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I made an very simple Ajax in Laravel. I wanted to replace a message in the view after clicking on a button with a message that comes from the controller.

I get an 500 Internal Server Error, i searched and saw that token is often the reason for the error. I added one, but it is still not working. Anyone who had the problem before?

```
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    })

    function getMessage(){
        console.log('test');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajax',
            dataType:'text',
            success:function(data){
                $("#msg").html(data.msg);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The Message that should be replaced and Button:

```
<div id = 'msg'>This message will be replaced using Ajax.
                Click the button to replace the message.</div>
            <button class="AjaxButton" onclick="getMessage()">Nachricht message</button>
        </div>
```

The Controller:

```
public function ajax(Request $request){
    console.log ('controller');
    $msg = "This is a simple message.";
    return response()->json('msg'->$msg);
}
```

The Route:

```
Route::post('/home/ajax','crudController@ajax');
```

[image]

Comment: `500 server error` is just a generic message, the real error, which will tell you exactly what is wrong, will be in your `storage/logs/laravel.log`, and/or your webserver (Apache, nginx) and/or PHP logs.  What is the real error?

Comment: local.ERROR: Trying to get property of non-object {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property of non-object at /project/source/app/Http/Controllers/crudController.php:104)
[stacktrace]

Comment: This is the error i get in the logs

Comment: Yes - that's from `'msg'->$msg` in your `json` response.  @Black already fixed it for you in his answer.

Comment: I changed it but is doesnt help - still 500 internal server error

Comment: Again, 500 server error is just a generic message, the real error, which will tell you exactly what is wrong, will be in your storage/logs/laravel.log.  You probably have solved the first problem and have a new error now ...

Comment: do you have in your html :

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: Please show us your current code.

Answer (score 1):

laravel comes with [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). axios already include csrf_token in ajax method..

```
axios.post("{{ route('your_route') }}")
.then(function (response) {
    $("#msg").html(response.data.msg);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

edit

```
axios.post({{ route ('') }}, {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone',
    address : 'Address example'
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` does not exist in PHP.
Remove it and it should work.

Open your `.env` file and change `APP_DEBUG` to true (`APP_DEBUG=true`)
To see more details about the errors.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors

---

Also try to change your ajax request to this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/home/ajax',
        data: '_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
        success: function(response){
            $("#msg").html(response.msg);
        }
    });
```

And in your Controller change your ajax function to this:

```
public function ajax(Request $request)
{
    $msg = "This is a simple message.";
    return response()->json(array('msg'=> $msg), 200);
}
```

---

There is something wrong with your Laravel setup, normally you should see an error message like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I deleted it - unfortunately its still not working

Comment: Open your `.env` file and change `APP_DEBUG` to true (`APP_DEBUG=true`)

Comment: My debug is already set so true - but there are no more details to the error (error is in the browser console)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot where we see your page and the error message?

Comment: I added a link in the description with the screenshot

Comment: @PeDore the only 2 real problems are removing `console.log` from your PHP, and fix the format of your `json()`@Black described both of these but maybe you missed them amongst the other stuff.

Comment: I changed what you said and now there is a 404 .. The link it refers to is /home/ajax and not /index.php/home/ajax ... Do you know this problem? I had it some times before that i had to manually add index.php in the url and another time it works without manually adding anything - both at the same place...

Comment: There is something wrong with your laravel, look at my updated answer, normally you should get a detailed error message on server errors like the one I posted.